# How to match a string of alphabet characters but no digits in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to match cites in French using regular expressions in Python.
So basically I would like to match any string made of alphabet characters, including accent characters but with no digits in the string.

from what I understood, there's no equivalent of "and" for regular expressions

Does anyone know another way to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: post the example string and the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to exclude digits in your names, you can try this.

```
re.search('^[^\d]+$', name)
```